Laravel/ MySQL basic audit using triggers
For an API using Laravel and MySQL we are trying to setup an audit mechanism using MySQL triggers.
We've extended Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager with something like
    public function connection($name = null)
    {
        $conn = parent::connection($name);

        $conn->statement("SET @app_user_id=?", [Auth::user()->id ?? 'no_login']);

        return $conn;
    }

Then inside the BEFORE UPDATE trigger we get @app_user_id and set the updated_by. This seems to be working well, is there a better way to do this, we don't want to use eloquent model events and we are fine using MySQL triggers, what possible issues we may face? Example:

When multiple users are using the application at the same time is it possible that we face race conditions, say due to connection pool reuse, and same @app_user_id is used among requests by different users?
We noticed DatabaseManager->connection() is called a lot and also there may be cases we don't want to set the @app_user_id at all, example when doing a mass update through a command. Could we set the @app_user_id inside a middleware, maybe extending Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate without loosing something? Is it possible the DB update that happens later will use a different connection that doesn't have @app_user_id set ?

Thanks in advance and please let me know if more explanation is needed.

If the connection pool is leaking session variables between requests, then that's a bug. Connection pools are supposed to reset all session-related state when they give a connection to any requestor. It would be extremely bad for security if variables or temp tables or transactions leaked between requests.

@BillKarwin Thanks. With that out of the way do you see any issues setting the @app_user_id inside a middleware? Is it safe doing it that way? Does laravel use the same session variables throughout the whole request? Btw if you could reply with an answer about that I would accept it.

I don't use Laravel, but if it works like any other connection-pool using framework in my experience, then you're not guaranteed to get the same connection each time you call connection(). You can only rely on that if you use the same $conn before it goes out of scope, or if you pass that $conn instance to other functions. Once you call connection() again to request a connection from the pool, you must assume it's a different connection. Even if it's technically the same connection, the pool has reset state (like session variables).

I'm not sure if Laravel is an exception to any of what I wrote above, so I don't want to post this as an answer.

You could test whether the connection is the same by using SELECT CONNECTION_ID(); after your code acquires a connection from the connection pool. These connection id's are maintained on the MySQL Server side. They are the id's you see in SHOW PROCESSLIST. A connection pool opens its set of connections, and recycles them for clients. But the connection id's should remain fixed. Eventually a connection pool does close a connection and open a new one, but less frequently than clients request to "borrow" one from the pool.

Since no activity I'll answer my own question.
Using triggers for basic audit seems the best option as it covers everything with minimum code updates.
Turns out Laravel uses the same connection (as expected) throughout the request unless something exceptional occurs (disconnect or some other failure), so we decided to go with extending Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager and overriding connect() method and set the @app_user_id there. This works globally. To enable/ disable in code we added another variable @audit_triggers_on that is checked in trigger SQL.
A more "Laravel" solution would be to use events to set the @app_user_id when user authenticates. In this case, if we wanted to also cover the scenario of DB failure, the reconnect() method could be overridden instead. That method get's called only when required, i.e. an actual disconnect occurred and can set @app_user_id only then. But in real cases this probably is not needed because the possibility for a database to fail and recover during the same request is probably zero, since we are talking about web app that requests take a few seconds and many implementations offer redundancy at database level anyway.
